# How can I capture/record responses of a list of choices in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm stuck on this and I can not figure out a solution.

I'm building an iOS app that will provide a list of favorites to a user.

Example, it will list 10 items which a user will have to select their favorite vs another item

So you may have:

Ice Cream vs Cake
Apple vs Orange
XBox vs PS4
etc....

I can't seem to figure out how will I be able to store the answers that the user selects?

The view will be two buttons side by side with the "VS" in the middle. When the user selects one  of the choices it should highlight their selection (10 in total since their are 10 selections to make) and then after they provide their answers to their favorites they can submit their responses.

Again, I just don't know how to capture those responses? Has anyone done something as suck already.

Comment: What does your attempt look like?

Comment: Have you looked at `CoreData`? `UserDefaults`?

Comment: The [Apple SwiftUI Tutorial - Handling User Input](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) has en example for this scenario